# Makefile : what is the difference between '-j' option and '-l' option?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I was reading GNU make manual and I got a question..

Regarding the parallel execution, I don't get the differece between `-j` option and `-l` options.

As I understand, they have the same role to limit the jobs number.
But the manual tells me that two options are different.

Please answer. Thanks!

Comment: `man make` seems to be quite descriptive, even for me that I have never used `makefile`.

Answer (score 3):

As said above, `man make` is pretty explicit, if you know what `load-average` means, which is for instance summarized in this [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/23498/what-does-load-average-mean-in-unix-linux). To paraphrase the documentation,

- `-j N` will let `make` attempt to launch up to `N` commands in parallel, regardless of what else might be running on the system.
- `-l N` will let `make` attempt to launch new commands only if the `load-average`, i.e. the average number of processes trying to obtain some CPU time during the last few moments, is less than `N`. It's thus more friendly towards other tasks that are running in parallel to your compilation.

Comment: Does this two options should be given together? if you give just `make -l2` by default make runs only one job at a time so it doesn't make any sense to give `-l2` option.

Comment: Thanks! I could get concepts of those options by your favor.

Answer (score 0):

Make by default starts 1 job. If you want to use all your CPUs/Cores use -j X. 
If you are afraid your machine gets overloaded add -l Y

Comment: Thanks for a simple and nice answer!!